# How to convert timestamp in the form of yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:SS.mil to epoch time in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table that has a timestamp attribute of the form `2022-01-01 01:09:23.500`. this needs to be converted to epoch time of the form `16409795630000`.

Do we have anything like this in Athena?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right your question,

Have you tried this exemple

```sql
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(s,
'1970-01-01 00:00:00',
your date)
AS BIGINT)
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach. What is "s" here. Let me be more specific:
Lets' say the table we have is ABC and the column we have is XYZ. If I query this column, I get the following:

XYZ
2021-06-17 00:51:43.432;
2021-06-17 00:00:16.755;
2021-06-17 00:00:27.195;
2021-06-17 00:00:28.262;

I need to convert this into their equivalent epoch time.

Comment: Anyways, after a few hit and trial, I got the solution:

cast(cast(to_unixtime(CAST(date_col AS timestamp)) as bigint) * 1000000 as varchar)

This converts the timestamp into epoch time.